# what is the behaviour of an asynchronous transaction in infinispan cache?

Tags: asynchronous, transactions, infinispan

I'm investigating asynchronous transaction in order to improve performances.

Could you please explain me what is the behaviour of a transaction in a replicated asynchronous cache?

If I have a transaction composed by operations, in which every operation depends by previous operation (i.e. order of execution of operations is important).

For instance, consider a transaction T that performs a read of data1 needed to build data2, data2 is then written on cache.

TRANSACTION T {

```
    // 1° operation

    data1 = get(key1);



    // 2° operation

    data2 = elaborate(data1);



    // 3° operation

    put(data2);
```

}

In other words, I need that "entire transactions" are asynchronously executed, but I need that operations performed inside a transaction remain synchronous.

Is it possible? If yes, how I have to configure infinispan?

Many Thanks

Francesco Sclano

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've wrapped those operations into `tm.begin(); try { ... tm.commit(); } catch (...) { tm.rollback(); }`.
There are few other option, therefore, I assume you use the default - optimistic transactions and 2-phase commit. I'd also recommend enabling write skew check - this should be default in Infinispan 7 but in prior versions you had to enable it explicitly, and some operations behave weird without that.

As for the `get`, this is always synchronous - you have to wait for the response.
Before `commit`, the `put` does basically just another `get` (in order to return the value) and records that the transaction should do the write during commit.

<strike>Then, during commit, the `PrepareCommand` which locks all updated entries is sent asynchronously - therefore, you can't know whether it succeeded or failed (usually due to timeout, but also due to write skew check or changed value in conditional command).</strike>

Second phase, the `CommitCommand` which overwrites the entries and unlocks the locks is sent synchronously after that - so you wait until the response is received. However, if you have `<transaction useSynchronization="true" />` (default), even if this command fails somewhere, the commit succeeds.
In order to send the `CommitCommand` (or `RollbackCommand`) asynchronously, you need to configure `<transaction syncCommitPhase="false" syncRollbackPhase="false" />`.

I hope I've interpreted the sources correctly - and don't ask me why is it done this way. Regrettably, I am not sure whether you can configure the semantics "commit or rollback this transaction reliably, but don't report the result and let me continue" out of the box.

**EDIT:** The commit in asynchronous mode should be 1-phase as you can't check the result anyway. Therefore, it's possible that concurrent writes get reordered on different nodes and you'll get the cluster inconsistent, but you are not waiting for the transaction to be completed.

Anyway, if you want to execute the whole block atomically and asynchronously, there's nothing easier than to wrap the code into Runnable and execute it in your own threadpool. And with synchronous cache.